# System.InvalidCastException while return List from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to implement custom serializer for WCF application. I have found useful info at: http://pinckrow.blogspot.ru/2011/10/custom-serialization-in-wcf.html
My service is:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "testSvc")]
public interface IRemote
{
    [OperationContract]
    [CustomOperationBehavior]
    IList<TestClass> GetAll();
    [OperationContract]
    [CustomOperationBehavior]
    string someString();
}

public class Remote : IRemote
{

    public IList<TestClass> GetAll()
    {
        return Program.classes;
    }

    public string someString()
    {
        return "hello!";
    }
}
```

client implimentation:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(new BasicHttpSecurityMode())
{
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536 * 16
};
EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8989/test");
testSvcClient client = new testSvcClient(binding, epa);

foreach (OperationDescription od in client.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
{
    od.Behaviors.Add(new CustomOperationBehavior());
}

var s = client.someString(); // ok!
var all = client.GetAll(); // InvalidCastException at ValidateReturnArg in mscorlib
```

I dont understand the problem becouse `DeserializeReply(Message message, object[] parameters)` in `CustomMessageFormatter` returns valid value (List of TestClass entities), im already trying List and IList - its the same throws InvalidCastException. Help please.

added:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class TestClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public TestKind Kind { set; get; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<TestClass> Childs { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public TestClass Parent { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Value { set; get; }

    public TestClass()
    {
        Childs = new List<TestClass>();
    }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class TestKind
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { set; get; }
}
```

Program code:

```
public class Program
{
public static List<TestClass> classes; 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartWCF();
    Console.ReadKey();
    MakeTestObjects();
    TestWCF();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void MakeTestObjects()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        TestKindCache.Add(new TestKind() { Id = i });
    }

    classes = new List<TestClass>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < rnd.Next(5, 6); i++)
    {
        var parent = new TestClass()
        {
            Id = rnd.Next(0, 99999).ToString(),
            Kind = TestKindCache.GetFromCache(rnd.Next(0, 11))
        };

        classes.Add(parent);
    }
}

static void StartWCF()
{
    new Task(() =>
    {
        AutoResetEvent infinity = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8989/test");
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Remote), baseAddress))
        {
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
            {
                HttpGetEnabled = true,
                MetadataExporter =
                {
                    PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Default
                }
            };

            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            host.Open();
            infinity.WaitOne();
        }
    }).Start();

}

static void TestWCF()
{
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(new BasicHttpSecurityMode())
    {
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536 * 16
    };
    EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8989/test");
    testSvcClient client = new testSvcClient(binding, epa);

    foreach (OperationDescription od in client.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
    {
        od.Behaviors.Add(new CustomOperationBehavior());
    }

    var s = client.someString();
    var all = client.GetAll();
    client.Close();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

}
```

stack trace:

```
в System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.ValidateReturnArg(Object arg, Type paramType)
в System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PropagateOutParameters(IMessage msg, Object[] outArgs, Object returnValue)
в System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
в System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
в ConsoleApplication7.ServiceReference1.testSvc.GetAll()
в ConsoleApplication7.ServiceReference1.testSvcClient.GetAll() в c:\Users\ak\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:строка 59
в ConsoleApplication7.Program.TestWCF() в c:\Users\ak\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\Program.cs:строка 88
в ConsoleApplication7.Program.Main(String[] args) в c:\Users\ak\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\Program.cs:строка 23
в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: please include the definition of Program.classes in your question.

Comment: I have include all code, maybe it will needed

Comment: I have found that is successfuly returns object (and then I cat cast it to List). But. its not solution.

Comment: Can you include the details of the exception? This may helkp to narrow down the error. Also check if client and server use the same assembly which contains the TestClass class.

Comment: What is your stacktrace?

Comment: helb, Yes, they are using the same assembly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the interface specifies an `IList<>`.

While that is a perfectly logical idea and a good abstraction from a design point of view, .NET doesn't know what to deserialize incoming data to if all it knows is that it has to be an `IList<>`.

Change your interface to List<> and it will work.

I know, it's an implementation detail rather than an abstraction, but `IList<>` doesn't work and `List<>` does because now .NET knows what to deserialize to.

Comment: Please see above (my question post), im already trying List and IList - its the same throws InvalidCastException. I have founded what array works correctly!